# Create a script that create another script

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to make a script that make a script that create a file in the folder stocked

Here I'm stocking the folder path of Banana in stock
then I want to create a file in that folder

```
echo "stock=banana/" >> test.sh
echo "touch $stock/file" >> test.sh
```

When I open test.sh :

```
stock=banana/
touch /file
```

why isn't `$stock` there?

Comment: BTW, note that `touch $stock/file` isn't safe in general -- that'll fail badly if the content of that variable contains whitespace, and particularly if it breaks into words that can be expanded as a glob character. Always quote your expansions: `touch "$stock"/file` or `touch "$stock/file"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Doing It Right

If the content you want to insert is hardcoded, use a quoted heredoc:

```
# Because of the quotes around EOF, nothing inside this heredoc is modified.
cat >test.sh <<'EOF'
stock=banana/
touch "$stock/file"
EOF
```

If it's *not* hardcoded, then an unquoted heredoc becomes appropriate -- but requires some care:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^-- /bin/sh does not support any means of eval-safe quoting
#             ...a ksh derivative such as bash will provide printf %q

stock=banana/                    # Presumably this is coming from a generic source, ie. $1
printf -v stock_q '%q' "$stock"  # Generate an eval-safe quoted version of stock

# Because the sigil is not quoted, expansions inside the heredoc are performed unless
# they're escaped.
cat >test.sh <<EOF
stock=$stock_q
touch "\$stock/file"
EOF
```

Note that we're using `printf %q` to generate a safely-escaped version of the value and inserting *that* (in an unquoted context) into the generated script; and being sure to escape all expansions which are intended to be performed by the child shell (thus replacing `$stock` with `\$stock`).

#### Answering The "Why"

Your `"$stock"` was expanded by the original shell, before it was passed to `echo`.